# Declaracion de variable

Tags: java, variables

Estoy haciendo unos ejercicios de Java, como veis en el programa le pido al usuario si quiere seguir o no y evaluo la respuesta como veis

```
/**
 * ProbarLibro.java
 * Programa para probar la clase Libro
 * ==================================
 * 
 * @author Luis Quesada Romero
 */

// Pertece al paquete tarea_libro

package tarea_libro;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProbarLibro { // Clase principal ProbarLibro

  public static void main(String[] args) { // Método Main

    // Varialbes

    String comenzamos;

    // Inicio del programa

    System.out.println("BIENVENIDO\n");
    System.out.println("Este programa guarda los datos de dos libros y nos dira cual tiene más paginas");
    System.out.println("¿Comenzamos? s/n");

    // Guardamos la respuesta y la evaluamos para empezar o salir del programa
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    comenzamos = entrada.nextLine();

    if ( "s".equals(comenzamos) ) {
      System.out.println("Comenzamos!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Otra vez sera, buena suerte!");
    }

  } // Fin del método main

} // Fin de la clase pirncipal ProbarLibro
```

Mi duda viene en la condicion del If, veis como directamente evaluo "s" sin crear una variable por ejemplo `String respuesta = s` y luego evaluar, mi duda es que no se si esta bien sin crear variable o es mejor crear varible y evaluar.

Comment: Creo que siempre será mejor declarar variables para almacenar el String a comparar con la respuesta, en tu caso "s" y "n". Imagina que tienes muchas más preguntas y en un determinado momento quieres cambiar el idioma a inglés, deberás cambiar cada uno de los 's' por 'y' con el trabajo que ello conlleva y la posibilidad de cometer errores.

Comment: En realidad da mismo, todo depende de si quieres respetar las mejores practicas de programación, si es así puedes almacenar el valor en una variable estática que luego utilices para evaluar el String. Por ejemplo: `private static String COMENZAMOS = "s";`. Esta es una buena practica ya que te permite saber a ti y a otras personas cual es el objetivo de la variable. En cambio utilizar un literal directamente como `"s"` en realidad no te dice nada acerca su función.

Comment: justo me refiero a buenas practicas, porque ya he visto que es lo mismo, incluso he llegado a pensar que si fuese necesario podria crear dos variables si las preguntas al usuario son muchas:
respuestaSI = "s";
respuestaN0 = "n";
y asi poder manejar las situaciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso tiene un nombre en programación: "Magic values" (o en este caso, "magic strings").

Son valores literales que aparecen en el código y se usan para su ejecución.

En ciertas ocasiones son problemáticos por varios motivos:

- ¿qué significan? Si ves un código que hace `dias * 86400` es posible que no te des cuenta que está conviritiendo días a segundos. En cambio, `dias * SEGUNDOS_POR_DIA` es más claro.

  - Por otra parte, no todos los valores mágicos son iguales, y hay formas de hacerlos  más legibles. Por ejemplo si el código es `dias * 24 * 60 * 60` es mucho más legible que la primera forma.
- ¿son variables? Si tu código para calcular el IVA es `importe * 0.21`, cuando haya un cambio del porcentaje del IVA vas a tener que encontrar el sitio (o los sitios) de tu código donde este el 0.21 y cambiarlo. Quizás te dejes alguno. O quizás cambies un 0.21 que no se usaba para el IVA sino para otra cosa.

Así que en general es recomendable tener esos valores constantes definidos como constantes (p.ej un atributo `private static final String RESPUESTA_SI = "s";`). Pero dicho lo dicho:

- Tu programa es muy corto y fácil de leer y modificar.
- Solo hace una pregunta, así que no hay problema de que para una pregunta espere "s" y en otra "v" (verdadero).
- Si hubiera que hacer que el programa en otro idioma, de todas formas tendrías que reescribir todos los literales. No es un programa hecho con esa idea, así que tampoco hay que preocuparse mucho de eso.

En resumen: el programa lo veo correcto, pero conviene saber que cuando se hacen más programas más serios y complicados hay que tener cuidado con los Magic Strings.

Comment: Correcto y entendido.
Vengo del front end, y los únicos lenguajes que manejos son JS y todo lo que deriva de ellos.

Por eso me volvia loco, me explico, lo primero que leí de Java, es que era un lenguaje fuertemente tipado, y que me dejase declarar el literal "s" sin antes declarar variable con tipo y demás me hizo dudar mucho.